# Play, Scala, Ebean: Checking if relationship exists

Tags: scala, jpa, playframework, ebean

Consider a hypothetical situation where I have two models: `Company` and `User`, defined like so

```
case class Company(name: String) extends Model {
    @Id
    var id: Long = _
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    var admins: util.List[User] = new util.ArrayList[User]()
}

case class User(email: String) {
    @Id
    var id: Long = _
}
```

Next, I have a request coming in and I want to check if `user_id` 200 is an admin of a `company_id` 100.  The obvious solution is to fetch the company with that id, and then check iteratively in the `admins` list if a `user_id` but that is quite inefficient. What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the easiest way to solve this problem is to simply add relation from user to company. If you need calling such query then such relation has sense:

Here is relation added to User class:

```
@ManyToOne 
var company:Company = _
```

And here is example how to check if user(id=200) is admin of company(id=100):

```
val user = Ebean.find(classOf[User], 200L)
println(user.company.id==100L)
```

Second option here is using RawSql. We can do it in a way similar to this:

```
val sql="select u.company_id as id from user u where u.id=200"
val rawSql = RawSqlBuilder.parse(sql).create()

val query = Ebean.find(classOf[Company])
query.setRawSql(rawSql)         
val list = query.findList()             
println(list(0).id==100L)
```